# Mysql Table function and view returns null value

Tags: mysql, sql, function, view

I really don't know why  my function and view in phpmyadmin returns null instead of DATETIME.

This is my function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `return_file`( name varchar(10), number int ) 
RETURNS datetime
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN DECLARE transdate DATETIME;
SET trans_date = (SELECT `date` from `sample_table` WHERE `name_ref` = name and `ref_number` = number and `type` = 10); 
RETURN trans_date; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

While this is my view:

```
CREATE VIEW getsME as 
SELECT id,type,date,name_ref,ref_number,return_file(name_ref,ref_number) as transDate
FROM sample_table
WHERE type= 11
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: In function you selected type as 10 and in view creation you took type as 11 in where condition, so name and ref_number which are in type 11 may no be present in type 10 so its returning null.

Comment: What do you get if you run `SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE type IN (10, 11)`?